# LINQ - group by, then sum conditionally

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data set (cars):

```
Brand     DateSold    Amount  Bought/Sold
Toyota    06/07/2015  18.5    Bought
BMW       01/01/2016  25.15   Sold
Mercedes  06/06/2016  20.75   Bought
```

and I want to group by year and return the sum of the amounts i.e.:

```
Year Amount  
2015 -18.5   
2016 4.4
```

and output it into a listbox.

I can sum without the bought/sold condition:

```
var AmountsByYear = cars.GroupBy(i => i.Date.Year)
                        .Select(g => new { 
                            Year = g.Key,
                            Total = g.Sum(i => i.Amount)
                        }).ToList();
lstAmountsByYear.DataSource = AmountsByYear;
```

Comment: Use the condition inside the `Sum` expression, e.g. something like `g.Sum(i => i.IsSold ? i.Amount : -i.Amount)`

Comment: @IvanStoev - this should be posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't given much detail on the how the "Bought/Sold" field is defined in your data structure, I suggest you use an enum. For example,

```
public class Car
{
    public string Brand;
    public DateTime Date;
    public double Amount;
    public BusinessType BusinessType;
}

public enum BusinessType
{
    Bought = -1,
    Sold = 1
}
```

This would enable you use your query with minimum change as following to get the expected result.

```
var AmountsByYear = cars.GroupBy(i => i.Date.Year)
                    .Select(g => new { 
                        Year = g.Key,
                        Total = g.Sum(i => i.Amount*(int)i.BusinessType)
                    }).ToList();
```

Input Data,

```
var cars = new List<Car>
{
    new Car{Brand="Toyota", Date = new DateTime(2015,06,07),Amount=18.5,BusinessType=BusinessType.Bought},
    new Car{Brand="BMW", Date = new DateTime(2016,01,01),Amount=25.15,BusinessType=BusinessType.Sold},
    new Car{Brand="Mercedes", Date = new DateTime(2016,06,06),Amount=20.75,BusinessType=BusinessType.Bought},
};
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating an extension method of `Car` that converts the combination of [`Amount`, `bought`/`sold`] into a positive or negative value for `Amount`:

```
public static decimal ToProperAmountValue(this Car car)
{
    return car.IsCarBought ? -car.Amount : car.Amount;
}
// TODO: invent proper method name
```

Furthermore, use the correct [overload of Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__) that already does the Select for you:

```
var amountsByYear = cars.GroupBy(

    // KeySelector: Group Cars into Groups of same year
    car => car.Date.Year)

    // ResultSelector: take the Key and the Cars with this Key to make a new object
    (year, carsInThisYear => new
    { 
        Year = year,
        Total = carsInThisYear.Sum(car => car.ToProperAmountValue())
    })
    .ToList();
```